# Why do my custom post types show up in the dashboard, but not on my site?

Tags: custom-post-types

I added the following code to my functions.php file to create a custom post type.

```
  function create_post_type() {
      register_post_type( 'mysite_reviews',
          array(  
              'labels' => array(  
                  'name' => __( 'Reviews' ),
                  'singular_name' => __( 'Review' )
              ),  
          'public' => true,  
          'menu_position' => 5,  
          'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'reviews')
          )  
      );  
  }  

add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
```

I then created a copy of my single.php file named single-mysite_reviews.php.

I went to my Wordpress dashboard and the custom post type was showing up in my menu. I created a new post from the new menu and published it. When I tried to view this new post all I could get was an error. Or more specifically, this page: http://gointrigue.com/vanilla/reviews/my-site-reviews-custom-post-type/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`flush_rewrite_rules()` as soon as you register the custom post type. It appears that they have not been rewritten yet, that is, most probably, why you're getting an embarrassing message.

```
register_post_type( 'mysite_reviews',
        array(  
            'labels' => array(  
                'name' => __( 'Reviews' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Review' )
            ),  
        'public' => true,  
        'menu_position' => 5,  
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'reviews')
    )
);
flush_rewrite_rules(); // <- do this only once!
```

Alternatively you can go to Settings -> Permalinks -> Save changes, which calls on [`flush_rewrite_rules()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) for you.

In fact http://gointrigue.com/vanilla/?post_type=mysite_reviews shows your post, which means that it's just not being rewritten due to the lack of the proper rules, which have not yet been flushed to the database.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. Resaving my permalink settings did the trick instantly. I should have figured it had something to do with that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are most welcome; glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you want to achieve from your description but, if you want a custom post type in the loop, do this:

```
// Add the 'your_post_type' postype to the loop.
add_action('pre_get_posts', function(WP_Query $query){
    if(is_admin() or is_preview()){
        return;
    }
    // Only add them to the loop on Home/Front-Page
    if((is_home() or is_front_page()) and empty($query->query_vars['suppress_filters']){
        // This has to be an array so fix it if required
        $post_types = $query->get('post_type');
        if(empty($post_types)) $post_types = array('post');
        elseif(is_string($post_types)) $post_types = array($post_types);
        // Add one or more CPT-s to the loop here (merge old with new)
        $query->set('post_type', array_merge($post_types, array(
            'your_post_type',
            // 'another_post_type',
            // 'maybe_another_post_type',
    )));
    }
    return;
});
```

Custom post types require a bit more manual tuning when you use them. Not only do you need to enable them but also list them or add them to the loop, create an archive *(or at least link to it)*.

**PS**: *Code uses PHP 5.3+ Closures. Convert to PHP 5.2 yourself, as an assignment :)*